# What does -ssh mean in SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

A previous employee at the company i work for had set up an SSH Tunnel but I am having some difficulty with it.

```
echo y | plink.exe -ssh -R 24011:localhost:1433 connect@testsite1.fern.io
```

My understanding is this is creating a reverse SSH tunnel with the port 24011 on the local machine listening. My question is what does "-ssh" refer to. I have searched everywhere but the nature of the search query makes it difficult to find any meaningful information.

Answer (score 2):

`-ssh` forces plink to use the SSH protocol. It can be left out. Found [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#7.2):

```
Z:\sysosd>plink
PuTTY Link: command-line connection utility
Release 0.53
Usage: plink [options] [user@]host [command]
       ("host" can also be a PuTTY saved session name)
Options:
  -v        show verbose messages
  -load sessname  Load settings from saved session
  -ssh -telnet -rlogin -raw
            force use of a particular protocol (default SSH)
  -P port   connect to specified port
  -l user   connect with specified username
  -m file   read remote command(s) from file
  -batch    disable all interactive prompts
The following options only apply to SSH connections:
  -pw passw login with specified password
  -L listen-port:host:port   Forward local port to remote address
  -R listen-port:host:port   Forward remote port to local address
  -X -x     enable / disable X11 forwarding
  -A -a     enable / disable agent forwarding
  -t -T     enable / disable pty allocation
  -1 -2     force use of particular protocol version
  -C        enable compression
  -i key    private key file for authentication
```